# Apple Script to Export from application

Tags: applescript

I'm new to AppleScript and wanted to export my citations using AppleScript. I found the following but am not sure the structure to change the following to my path folders, can you please provide an example and is this executed in the Script editor?:

```
tell application "Papers" 
set outFolder to ((path to desktop from user domain) as string) & "PDF Files" 
export ((publication item of every primary file item) as list) as PDF Files to outFolder 
end tell
```

Thanks

Comment: This script would be run within **Applications > Utilities > Script Editor.app**. Please could you edit your question and expand on what you mean by *change the following to my path folders*.

Comment: @GrahamMin I wanted to know am I supposed to change this script with an actual file path or just copy this script directly like it is in the script editor? Because when I do that and run the script it does not work.

Comment: Good to hear it worked. Please can you [close this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To better understand the AppleScript, try breaking it down.

Within **Script Editor.app** run the following:

```
set outFolder to ((path to desktop from user domain) as string) & "PDF Files"
```

After running, the **Result** panel will show the value `outFolder` is set to. This should be a path to a folder called `PDF Files` on your Desktop.

Does this folder exist on your Mac? If not, this is probably the cause of the problems you are seeing.

The next line in the AppleScript tells the application **Papers** to export to that folder. If you have problems with Paper's AppleScript behaviour, [do contact the developers](http://support.papersapp.com/mac); they will be best placed to help you.

### Add a Try Block

You can [add a **try** block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978199/applescript-on-error-try-line-number) around your AppleScripts. These will provide better error messages and hopefully catch problems.

### Changing the Folder

You can add an interactive folder selection by replacing the `set outFolder…` line to:

```
set outFolder to choose folder
```

Alternatively, change the "PDF Files" to the name of your preferred folder.

Comment: Can I change the path of the folder? If I have this folder in another directory? Thanks

Comment: Try editing the "PDF File" constant; I have updated the answer.